# Fullcalendar v5 remove all events on button click

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to remove all events in fullcalendar v5 upon click of a button, the code below works fine

```
calendar.addEventSource([
    {
      title: 'Business Lunch',
      start: '2020-04-03T01:00:00',
    },
]);
```

But how can I able to remove/clear/delete all events after button click?
The older version of fullcalendar has this method

```
calendar.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', []);
```

How about for v5? I tried the code below but it gives me an error `remove is not a function`. I even tried `calendar.refetchEvents();`but nothing works.

```
$('.button').click(function(event) {
    calendar.remove();
});
```

Comment: Did you check the v5 documentation? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5#toc . It's the same as in v4 anyway as far as I can see. You have to get all the events, loop through them and remove each one. Either that, or if you use event sources, you can remove the event source.

Comment: @ADyson I have actually run into this same issue. Something changed to the way those get accessed but I have not figured it all out fully.

Works for me in v4, I get the same error as OP in V5

Answer (score 12):

Fullcalendar v5 remove all events

```
calendar.removeAllEvents();
```

Comment: This should be marked as right answer, worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Must be called on an Event Source instance. Use getEventSources.

```
removeEvents = calendar.getEventSources();

removeEvents.forEach(event => {
     event.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@tta & @Leandro Lazzaretti:

Great answers! I was looking for this, and both works, but I found out an important diffenrence between them:

```
calendar.removeAllEvents(); // This will NOT clear the events source array
```

and

```
removeEvents = calendar.getEventSources();

removeEvents.forEach(event => {
     event.remove(); // this will clear 
});
```

You can check it out by doing:

```
removeEvents = calendar.getEventSources();

removeEvents.forEach(event => {
    event.remove();
});
        
calendar.addEventSource('yourSourceHere');
var e = calendar.getEventSources();
console.log(e);
```